# How to build react files for electronjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, electron

I am building an app using electron and react. When I run build on react and try to use the files in electron I end up having [image: error in electron webdev tools]

I used the starter template for electron [here](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/quick-start#create-the-main-script-file):

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

function createWindow() {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  })

  win.loadFile('UI/index.html');
}

app.whenReady().then(createWindow)

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

app.on('activate', () => {
  if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
    createWindow()
  }
})
```

Is there any way to make electron sort of those files such that the HTML file will not look for the js file in the "/" directory?

Answer (score 0):

I believe we'd need to see more of your project (perhaps post a github repo of it?) in order to help. Looks like a webpack error from the looks of your picture.

I'd like to recommend [`secure-electron-template`](https://github.com/reZach/secure-electron-template) (*DISCLAIMER*: I am the author) that has React support with Electron built in from the get-go.

Comment: I am sorry but I cant show any of the react code sadly :'(. I will try your recommendation however. Thanks you